# Homogeneous space and Uniform Subgroup of Lie groups

Tags: differential-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras, normal-subgroups, homogeneous-spaces

I'm trying to figure out how a homogeneous space is built, and I know the theorem  below:

**Theorem**:   Let $G$ be a Lie group, and $H$ closed normal subgroup of $G$. Then the cosets space $G/H$ with the induced group structure is a Lie group.

My question is " what would be Lie algebra of $G/H$, and its vector fields associated flows if $H$ had only *uniform (discrete) subgroup* instead of *closed normal subgroup*.

(Remark: A subgroup $A$ of $G$ is called a uniform subgroup If $G/H$ is compact.)

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous regarding whether you are stating a definition or a theorem. Also, your question is rather unfocussed: Are you asking *how* $G/H$ is defined? Alternatively, are you asking for a *proof* that $G/H$ is a Lie group? In either case, have you read what is written about these issues somewhere and if so do you have a specific *mathematical question* regarding that definition/proof?

Comment: Thank you for answering. What I'm wondering is this, what would be $G/H$ algebra,vector fields and its flow  if  $H$ had only uniform (discrete) subgroup properties instead of  closed normal subgroup properties. @LeeMosher

Comment: That's quite different from what you've written, so you should probably rewrite your question to clarify what you really want to know.

Comment: Are you asking "How should one define the Lie algebra of $G/H$ in the case where $H$ is not assumed to be normal, but discrete and uniform$? I don't think there is a reasonable definition for a Lie algebra for such settings. Although maybe there is and I just never heard of it...